# footer scripts do not work in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have Created the `MY_Controller` in the `core` folder. In which I declared `public $footerScript;`. Here is the code of `MY_Controller`.

```
 <?php
    class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
    {
       public $footerScript;
       public $data = array();
        public function __construct()
        {
            date_default_timezone_set( 'Asia/Karachi' );
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->library(array('ion_auth','form_validation'));
            $this->data['C_FullName'] = 'CodeigNiter Shop';
            $this->data['C_ShortName'] = 'CI Shop';
            }
    }
    ?>
```

This `Home Controller` extends the `MY_Controller`. This `Home Controller` shows the `add_items` file in the `views` folder.

```
    <?php
    class Home extends MY_Controller
    {
      public function __construct()
      {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('image_lib');
      }
      public function items()
      {
          $this->show("admin/add_items");
      }
}
?>
```

This is the `form` in the `add_items` in which I give `id` to the `submit` button. When I click this button a `jquery` `event` will be called :

```
<form id="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Header Text" class="control-label" > Title </i></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Title" id="title" name="title" class="form-control" tabindex="1">
         </div>
         <!-- /.form-group -->
      </div>
       <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <input type="submit" name="submit" id="Add" value="Add Items" class="btn btn-success">
      </div>
      <!-- iCheck -->
   </div>
   <!-- /.col (right) -->
</form>
```

and this code is written at the end of the `add_items` file. The links in the `script` tag are working fine but when I click the button to show `alert` it does not work.

```
    <?php
        //This Section footerScripts Should Execute In Footer/End of the Page.
        $this->footerScript = sprintf('
        <script src="'.base_url().'assets/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="'.base_url().'assets/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>        
         <script type="text/javascript">
                  $("#Add").on("click", function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                         var title= $("#title").val();
                         alert(title); return false;
                       }
         </script>
        ');
        ?>
```

Comment: On click are you sure control goes in your JavaScript script? You can console something before "var title" to see it actually get hit after click on submit button

Comment: I write console.log(title) but it also not works. I think it cannot access the javascript code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using jquery, don't forget to add a document ready like:

```
$(function() {
  $("#Add").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var title= $("#title").val();
    alert(title); return false;
  }    
});
```

now it waits to execute your function until the DOM is loaded completely. see [docs](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)