# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined - Datepicker - Codeigniter 3

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, codeigniter-3

greetings!

First of all, thank you so much for the help!

Scenario:

1° I use codeigniter

2° I added this very simple script in my VIEW FILE.

(https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default)

3° This is the error message that i receive in the browser:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at VM113 info:21
(anonymous) @ VM113 info:21
```

**This my controller method:**

```
public function info()
{
    $data['pagetitle'] = 'general use';

    $this->load->view('theme/header1');
    $this->load->view('multiform/register2',$data);
    $this->load->view('theme/footer');
}
```

**This my Header VIEW file: header1**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>  
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>Teste</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/testelib/jquery-ui.min.css">   

<script type="text/javascript" defer src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/testelib/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" defer src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/testelib/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>

    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    inline: true
    });
</script>
```

**This my VIEW file: register2**

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

**PS:** If i make this example with "all files in the same folder", the script works normally.

Just because the **.js and .css Links** of the Jquery Libraries are in separeted files, i got this conflict.

What should i do please?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: What is the `base_url()` value? could you open that js link in a new tab (from view page source)?

Comment: yes @Hasta Dhana! i can open that js and css link in a new tab (from view page source).

About the base_url, it returns your site base URL, as specified in your config file.


[link]https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#base_url

Comment: Since you are using jquery, don't forget to add a document ready: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55265341/2275490

Comment: Hello @Vickel,


Thank you so much for your tipp, But as i added this script line, now i get this error message:

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
    

at info:23 
(anonymous) @ info:23

Comment: try using jquery and jquery-ui from their cdn: https://code.jquery.com/

Comment: Hello @Vickel, Thank you so much for your tipp, i added the **CDN links** as suggested, but this is not still the solution, i get the same error message.

Comment: try to put the whole thing (loading .js files and your script with the document ready) into the very end of the footer

Answer (score 1):

include this script to include jquery:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

$ symbol is not defined since jquery is not included in the script

Comment: Hello @236379 ktr.et.cse.16,

Thank you so much for your tipp, But as i added this script line, now i get this error message:

    **Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function**
    
    **at info:23 **
    **(anonymous) @  info:23**


I changed the script for this example, but the error message is still the same:

    <script>
     $( function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
      } );
    </script>

    Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
    
     at info:23 
    (anonymous) @  info:23

What should i still try?

Comment: implement datepicker like this : 
`$(document).ready(function() {

    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    inline: true
    });
});`

Comment: Hello @236379 ktr.et.cse.16,

Thank you so much for your tipp, But as i added this script line, now i get this error message:

**Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function**
    

**at info:23 
(anonymous) @ info:23**

Comment: You will also need to include the script for the jQuery UI. <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Answer (score 0):

, Guys, Thank you so much for your tipps, help and attention.
After 4 days of a lot of pain, i found a Post that gave me a way that guided to answer.

A answer from @TimBrownlaw gave me a light.
[jquery javascript doesnt work in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796517/jquery-javascript-doesnt-work-in-codeigniter)

There is a compatibility between those links format:

```
<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/lib/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
```

And this link format:

```
<?php echo base_url("assets/lib/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"); ?>"
```

But i think, until today i have made this wrong even that i've already read the whole C.I documentation.

The documentation says openly so, use the base_url like this:

1° echo base_url("blog/post/123");

2° echo base_url("images/icons/edit.png");

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#base_url

base_url with *controllername*, *method* and *parameter* INSIDE the (parentheses) and NOT OUTSIDE.

Another problem was the **"defer"** attribute with the  elements. This means that jQuery won't load until after all the other html loads.

But this bit of code will try run as soon as the view is loaded.

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({inline: true});
```

Of course, it fails - jQuery hasn't loaded yet so $ is not defined.

i removed the "defer" attr from the  tags and it runs!.

**Well, that's it! Thanks a lot everyone! It works!**